# When talking about "driving", are "pull off" & "pull over" almost the same?

Tags: word-meaning

> [Pull over](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pull-over?q=pull%20over): (of a vehicle or its driver) to move to the side of
>   the road in order to stop or let something pass
>
> [pull off | pull off something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pull-off?q=pull%20off): (of a vehicle or its driver) to
>   leave the road in order to stop for a short time

So, When talking about "**driving**", are "**pull off**" & "**pull over**" almost the same?

What are the differences between "**pull off**" & "**pull over**"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> pull off
> pull over

are similar.  When you *pull over* you are usually along the road you were previously traveling on.  In fact the colloquial phrase

> to be **pulled over**

usually means to be stopped by the police
[image]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/97Wk2-_MJgE/maxresdefault.jpg))</sub>

whereas

> to pull off a highway

is to leave the main roadway, usually by an exit ramp, it does not imply slowing down and stopping as being *pulled over* might

[image]

On a long driving trip you might *pull over* by first *pulling off* the highway to find accommodations.

Your last usage

> to pull off something

has a completely different meaning which is to accomplish a difficult task which doesn't necessarily have any relationship to its meaning for driving.